# I got an error using this build.grafle file and don't know how to fix it

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Here's the Error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file '/home/wieland/GitGradlePackaging/build.gradle' line: 22
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'GitGradlePackaging'.
>
>   > Could not get unknown property 'org' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.

And Here's my build.gradle File:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Quickstart chapter in the Gradle
 * user guide available at https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html
 */

//From example: http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.at/2015/04/gradle-goodness-use-git-commit-id-in.html



buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        //Add dependencies for build script, so we can access Git from our build script     
        classpath 'org.ajoberstar:grgit:1.1.0'
    }
    def git = org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.open(file('.'))
    //To save Githash
    def githash = git.head().abbreviatedId
}

plugins {
    // Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
    id 'java'

    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building an application
    id 'application'

    // Apply the groovy plugin to also add support for Groovy (needed for Spock)
    id 'groovy'

    id 'distribution'
}


// Set version
project.version = mainProjectVersion + " - " + githash

project.ext.set("wholeVersion", "$project.version - $githash")
project.ext.set("buildtimestamp", "2000-01-01 00:00")

def versionfilename = "versioninfo.txt"



def GROUP_DEBUG = 'Debug'
// Task to print project infos
task debugInitialSettings {
    group = GROUP_DEBUG
    doLast {
        println 'Version: ' + project.wholeVersion
        println 'Timestamp: ' + project.buildtimestamp
        println 'Filename: ' + project.name 
    }
}

// To add the githash to zip
task renameZip {
    doLast {
        new File ("$buildDir/distributions/$project.name-${project.version}.zip")
        .renameTo ("$buildDir/distributions/$project.name-${project.wholeVersion}.zip")
    }
}
distZip.finalizedBy renameZip

// To add the githash to tar
task renameTar{
    doLast {
        new File ("$buildDir/distributions/$project.name-${project.version}.tar")
                .renameTo ("$buildDir/distributions/$project.name-${project.wholeVersion}.tar")
    }
}
distTar.finalizedBy renameTar


// Define the main class for the application
mainClassName = 'App'

dependencies {
    // This dependency is found on compile classpath of this component and consumers.
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'

    // Use the latest Groovy version for Spock testing
    testCompile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.13'

    // Use the awesome Spock testing and specification framework even with Java
    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

//To generate Testreports as HTML
test {
    reports {
        junitXml.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
    }

}

distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            from { 'build/docs' }
            into ('reports') {
                from 'build/reports'
            }
        }
    }
}




//To make sure that test and javadoc ran before zip and tar
distTar.dependsOn test
distZip.dependsOn test
distTar.dependsOn javadoc
distZip.dependsOn javadoc
```

Please keep in mind I have not much knowledge about gradle as I'm just starting to learn it!
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to move the githash definition outside the `buildscript` block

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        //Add dependencies for build script, so we can access Git from our build script     
        classpath 'org.ajoberstar:grgit:1.1.0'
    }
}

def git = org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.open(file('.'))
//To save Githash
def githash = git.head().abbreviatedId
```

The reason is that when the `buildscript` block is evaluated line by line, its dependencies are not yet loaded. When the rest of the script is evaluated, the dependencies of the `buildscript` block have already been loaded. This is actually the reason for the `buildscript` block existence: to be run before the rest of the build and prepare the setup.

Comment: Thanks for that! now it runs for some time, but then I get the following error:         * Where:
Build file '/home/wieland/GitGradlePackaging/build.gradle' line: 41

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'GitGradlePackaging'.
> Could not get unknown property 'mainProjectVersion' for root project 'GitGradlePackaging' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: `mainProjectVersion` is never defined.

Comment: Nvm, I didn't even need it